# MATLAB R2015b Installation Launcher problem

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I downloaded the Matlab R2015b student version for my Ubuntu 14.04 computer and tried installing it as per the installation guide for Linux/Unix machines. So the first step to that is to unzip the downloaded installation archive and then run ./install as superuser. When I do that, ideally the Matlab interactive installation launcher should come up on the screen and guides you through the installation. However when I do this, my terminal displays the following:

```
$./install

Preparing installation files ...

Installing ...

Finished
```

But the interactive launcher never shows up, and neither is Matlab installed when I check for it. These lines appear rather quickly (1-2 seconds) on the terminal, so it seems improbable that Matlab has been installed in any form.

I tried installing on another machine from the same installation archive I downloaded, and the installation launcher comes up immediately. So I believe the problem is on my machine, but I cannot figure out what it is.

Anyone facing the same issue and having resolved it, please help. Many thanks!

Comment: gnu octave is very similar to matlab.  I have have many issues with installing matlab on multiple platforms... anyhow, did you buy this iso from matlab, or did you download if from your college? You may be able to get good support from either place. The last time I installed matlab, I had to register online, before it would take my license. The installer kept crashing saying something like invalid licence.

Comment: Why do you think, that you start the installation as super user? I can't see a `sudo` or a root prompt in your question.

Comment: I want to say (but i'm not 100% certain) that the matlab installer prompts for root permission during its initialization.

Comment: j0h : It's just for the sake of interoperability within a project where not everyone is familiar with Octave. So, yeah!
And yes, root privileges are indeed needed for the install on Ubuntu. So it's better to sudo the install of MATLAB so that any required directories can be created and symbolic links can be made, while still keeping the application accessible to ordinary users and not just root.

Comment: A.B. : I only posted the instance when I tried as user, but I had also tried as superuser too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. The problem has been resolved - it seems that the archive I downloaded was corrupt in some way. I realised this when I downloaded the archive again from the Mathworks website a few minutes ago and tried to install it again, and low and behold, it worked! I'm sorry to have wasted everyone's time without having tried that before. Now I only wonder whether the initial problem encountered was due to a poor internet connection and thus a faulty archive downloaded, or whether the .zip archive provided by Matlab is not the best archiving / compressing format.